# PyQt5: How to reset the content of a QtWidgets.QGroupBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `RadioButtonWidget` class that receives a list of names (`button_list`) and a `QtWidgets.QGroupBox` (`radio_group_box`) and creates a radio button for each name. The problem I have is that after creating the buttons, I cannot change them. That is if I call the class again with another list of names, nothing changes. I need to create a function inside my class to remove any existing radio buttons so that I can add a new list inside it.

I tried to do `radio_group_box.deleteLater()` outside the class but this removes the whole box.

```
class RadioButtonWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, radio_group_box, button_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.radio_group_box = radio_group_box
        self.radio_button_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()

        #create the radio buttons
        self.radio_button_list = []
        for each in button_list:
            self.radio_button_list.append(QtWidgets.QRadioButton(each))

        if button_list != []:
            #set the default checked item
            self.radio_button_list[0].setChecked(True)

        #create layout for radio buttons and add them
        self.radio_button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # add buttons to the layout and button group
        counter = 1
        for each in self.radio_button_list:
            self.radio_button_layout.addWidget(each)
            self.radio_button_group.addButton(each)
            self.radio_button_group.setId(each,counter)
            counter += 1

        # add radio buttons to the group box
        self.radio_group_box.setLayout(self.radio_button_layout)

    def selected_button(self):
        return self.radio_button_group.checkedId()
```

Comment: Some of your logic doesn't make much sense. You create a RadioButtonWidget, but that widget is never used. If you just want to add/remove buttons from a group box, you should use a function in the widget that contains that group box, or eventually subclass QGroupBox and create a function that sets its radio buttons internally. Just to clarify, are you using an interface built on Designer, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes I have created an interface using the designer where the radio_group_box is created

Comment: Is there going to be any other widget in that groupbox, or is it only used for the grouped radio buttons?

Comment: No it is only for the radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing the radio buttons, you can create a whole new radio button layout and set it for the group box exactly as you did in the constructor. Here is an example where the function `set_group_box_buttons` will remove the existing layout from `radio_group_box` (which is done by setting it to a temp widget), and add a new one with the new buttons.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class RadioButtonWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, radio_group_box, button_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.radio_group_box = radio_group_box
        self.set_group_box_buttons(button_list)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.radio_group_box)

    def selected_button(self):
        return self.radio_button_group.checkedId()

    def set_group_box_buttons(self, button_list):
        self.radio_button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.radio_button_list = [QRadioButton(x) for x in button_list]
        if button_list:
            self.radio_button_list[0].setChecked(True)

        if self.radio_group_box.layout():
            QWidget().setLayout(self.radio_group_box.layout())

        self.radio_button_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for i, v in enumerate(self.radio_button_list):
            self.radio_button_layout.addWidget(v)
            self.radio_button_group.addButton(v)
            self.radio_button_group.setId(v, i)
        self.radio_group_box.setLayout(self.radio_button_layout)


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rbw = RadioButtonWidget(QGroupBox('Radio Buttons'), ['Radio 1', 'Radio 2', 'Radio 3'])
        self.box = QLineEdit()
        self.box.returnPressed.connect(self.replace_buttons)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.rbw, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.box, 0, 1)

    def replace_buttons(self):
        self.rbw.set_group_box_buttons(self.box.text().split(', '))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To demonstrate, I added a QLineEdit which will update the names when you press enter. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: this answers my question. The only missing element is that when no text is provided in the box, there will be still a checked radio button with no label.

Answer (score 1):

There's a conceptual error in your code: you are creating a new RadioButtonGroup, which is a widget, but you are not using it.

As long as each group box will only contain the radio buttons, there is no need to create a new widget (especially if you're not actually using it); you just have to create a layout if the groupbox doesn't have one yet.

There are at least two possible approaches to your question.

For both of them I always use existing radios if possible, to avoid unnecessary object destruction each time the options change, so that they are removed only when the number of options decreases. This also avoids unnecessary layout updates (especially if the number of options is the same).

I also kept the logical "interface" consistent, providing the same method and behavior of `update_options(groupBox, options)`.

### QObject based group

With this implementation, I'm creating an object that acts as an interface responsible of creating a QButtonGroup and setting the options, while also providing signals for the state change or the current checked radio.

```
class RadioButtonGroup(QtCore.QObject):
    optionToggled = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, bool)
    optionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int)

    def __init__(self, radio_group_box, button_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.groupBox = radio_group_box
        layout = radio_group_box.layout()
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonToggled[int, bool].connect(self.changed)
        if layout is None:
            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(radio_group_box)
        for i, text in enumerate(button_list, 1):
            radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
            layout.addWidget(radio)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(radio, i)

    def button(self, id):
        return self.buttonGroup.button(id)

    def changed(self, i, state):
        self.optionToggled.emit(self, i, state)
        if state:
            self.optionChanged.emit(self, i)

    def selected_button(self):
        return self.buttonGroup.checkedId()

    def update_options(self, button_list):
        layout = self.groupBox.layout()

        # this method will keep the current checked radio as checked, if you want
        # to reset it everytime, just uncomment the next commented lines
        #self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)
        for i, text in enumerate(button_list, 1):
            radio = self.buttonGroup.button(i)
            if radio:
                #radio.setChecked(False)
                radio.setText(text)
            else:
                radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
                layout.addWidget(radio)
                self.buttonGroup.addButton(radio, i)
        #self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)

        if len(button_list) == len(self.buttonGroup.buttons()):
            return
        # there are more radios than needed, remove them
        for radio in self.buttonGroup.buttons():
            id = self.buttonGroup.id(radio)
            if id > i:
                self.buttonGroup.removeButton(radio)
                radio.deleteLater()


class ObjectBased(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('buttongroup.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.setOptions)
        self.groupBoxes = self.groupBox1, self.groupBox2, self.groupBox3
        self.radioButtonGroups = []
        for box in self.groupBoxes:
            group = RadioButtonGroup(box, 
                ['Option {}'.format(o + 1) for o in range(randrange(1, 10))])
            self.radioButtonGroups.append(group)
            group.optionChanged.connect(self.optionChanged)

    def setOptions(self):
        buttonGroup = self.radioButtonGroups[self.comboBox.currentIndex()]
        options = ['Option {}'.format(o + 1) for o in range(self.spinBox.value())]
        buttonGroup.update_options(options)

    def optionChanged(self, radioButtonGroup, id):
        groupBox = radioButtonGroup.groupBox
        print('{} checked {} ({})'.format(
            groupBox.title(), id, radioButtonGroup.button(id).text()))
```

### Self contained

In this mode, the logic is all within the window class. While this approach is slightly simpler than the other one, we're missing an unique "interface", which might be useful for access from external objects instead.

```
class SelfContained(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('buttongroup.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.setOptions)
        self.radioButtonGroups = []
        for g, groupBox in enumerate((self.groupBox1, self.groupBox2, self.groupBox3)):
            buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
            self.radioButtonGroups.append((groupBox, buttonGroup))
            buttonGroup.buttonToggled[int, bool].connect(lambda id, state, g=g: self.optionChanged(g, id, state))
            self.update_options(g, ['Option {}'.format(o + 1) for o in range(randrange(1, 10))])

    def update_options(self, groupId, button_list):
        groupBox, buttonGroup = self.radioButtonGroups[groupId]

        layout = groupBox.layout()
        if layout is None:
            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(groupBox)

        # as above...
        #buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)
        for i, text in enumerate(button_list, 1):
            radio = buttonGroup.button(i)
            if radio:
                #radio.setChecked(False)
                radio.setText(text)
            else:
                radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
                layout.addWidget(radio)
                buttonGroup.addButton(radio, i)
        #buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)

        if len(button_list) == len(buttonGroup.buttons()):
            return
        for radio in buttonGroup.buttons():
            id = buttonGroup.id(radio)
            if id > i:
                buttonGroup.removeButton(radio)
                radio.deleteLater()

    def setOptions(self):
        groupId = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
        options = ['Option {}'.format(o + 1) for o in range(self.spinBox.value())]
        self.update_options(groupId, options)

    def optionChanged(self, groupId, id, state):
        if state:
            groupBox, buttonGroup = self.radioButtonGroups[groupId]
            print('{} checked {} ({})'.format(groupBox.title(), id, buttonGroup.button(id).text()))
```